# How to download GitHub assets from the latest release via command line?

Tags: powershell, github, wget

https://github.com/irssi/irssi/releases/latest

I would like to have a set of command line commands to download the latest version of the two files (*.tar.gz and *.patch). The filename of the .tar.gz archive changes with the releases version so I can't get a static path for the filename.

Powershell commands preferred.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow. If you prefer powershell commands, then I recommend giving it a try. If you get stuck you can come back and show the code you’re having trouble with and we can assist.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` is what you're looking for. You may want to set `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` to work around an issue where the progress bar bottlenecks the performance of the cmdlet as it counts bytes too often when downloading. This is generally only an issue for larger files though. Try figuring out how to use `Invoke-WebRequest`, then come back with any issues you run into.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU Wget following way:

```
wget --recursive --level=1 --no-directories --accept-regex '(tar.gz|patch)$' https://github.com/irssi/irssi/releases/latest
```

which you should run in empty directory. Explanation: use recursive download option of wget with depth 1 (i.e. consider only links in page), do not create hierarchy mirroring that of site (i.e. put all in current working directory), look for links which do contain regular expression. Here `$` denotes end of string and `|` denotes *or*, so its meaning is: links ending with `tar.gz` or `patch`

*(tested in GNU Wget 1.20.3)*